# QProcess linuxdeployqt

Tags: qt, bash, qprocess

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Basher]

Здравствуйте! Я тут написал небольшую программку, типа GUI для linuxdeployqt, практически уже реализовал весь необходимый функционал, но столкнулся с одной маленькой проблемкой. Она как бы работает, но только если ее запустить непосредственно из QtCreator или соответствующей командой из терминала. Далее, пытаясь разобраться, я сделал еще одну программку, которая отлавливает из QtProcess коды ошибок (спасибо за помощь товарищу [Sergey Tatarincev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/365297/sergey-tatarincev)):

```
QString command = ui->lineEdit->text();
QProcess* p = new QProcess();
connect(p,&QProcess::readyReadStandardError,this,&MainWindow::slot_readyRead);
connect(p,&QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput,this,&MainWindow::slot_readyRead);
connect(p,static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int)>(&QProcess::finished),this,&MainWindow::slot_finished);
p->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << QString(command));
```

Потом ввел туда команду "linuxdeployqt /home/madmentat/Deploy/test/QtDeployer -unsupported-allow-new-glibc" и получил следующую ошибку:

```
     ERROR: linuxdeployqt  (commit d6ac06c), build 19 built on 2022-07-04 19:17:26 UTC
     WARNING: Not checking glibc on the host system.
     The resulting AppDir or AppImage may not run on older systems.
     ERROR:          This mode is unsupported and discouraged.
     For more information, please see
     https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/issues/340
     Not using FHS-like mode
     app-binary: "/home/madmentat/Deploy/test/QtDeployer"
     appDirPath: "/home/madmentat/Deploy/test"
     relativeBinPath: "QtDeployer"
     Keeping existing AppRun
     ERROR: ERROR: ldd outputLine: "/home/madmentat/Deploy/test/QtDeployer: /usr/lib            /x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/madmentat/Deploy/test/QtDeployer)"
     ERROR: for binary: "/home/madmentat/Deploy/test/QtDeployer"
     ERROR: Please ensure that all libraries can be found by ldd. Aborting.
     Process exited with code 1
```

Вывод, очевидно, такой: linuxdeployqt, ссылаясь на ldd, не видит библиотеки, хотя ldd, как уже проверено, все-таки находит их корректно. Еще я заметил, что файлы, создаваемые программой, запущенной через ярлык *.desktop, создаются не в директории программы, а в корне домашней папки, "~/". Тем временем, я, конечно, предварительно настраивал рабочую среду и у меня есть такой файл "~/.bashrc" со следующим содержимым:

```
     #add QT ENV
     export PATH=/home/madmentat/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin:$PATH
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/madmentat/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
     export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/madmentat/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/plugins:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH
     export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/home/madmentat/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/qml:$QML2_IMPORT_PATH
```

Ну и вот, теперь вопрос: в чем может быть ошибка и как сделать так, чтобы linuxdeployqt, запущенный через QProcess с ярлыка "*.desktop", нашел необходимые библиотеки Qt?!

Answer (score 0):

Наконец-то, поиски увенчались успехом. Поскольку проблема явно уперлась в потерянные библиотеки, я решил в этом убедиться и немножко модифицировал тестовую программу Basher, добавив под ui->setupUi(this); такой код:

```
QString PATH = qgetenv("PATH");
ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(PATH);
```

По идее, он должен вывести переменные окружения. И вот, при запуске приложения из командной строки или непосредственно из QtCreator ответ был следующий:

> home/madmentat/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin

А вот при вызове из самой ОС, через ярлык desktop ответ был такой:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Реально запарился искать решение, как исправить положение. В итоге помогла статья на [losst.ru](https://losst.ru/peremennye-okruzheniya-v-linux)

```
sudo rm  /etc/environment
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

И там должно быть следующее содержимое:

> PATH="/home/madmentat/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin"

Ну, тут, собственно, смысл в чем... Просто сложить первый и второй ответ, убрав повторяющиеся варианты, разграниченные двоеточием. В итоге, все заработало как надо. Таким образом, у меня теперь есть собственный QtDeployer с GUI и яркими кнопками. Если кому интересно, скачать можно [здесь](https://madmentat.ru/index.php/shpargalki/2-statejki/130-qtdeployer)